# При клике на кнопку проверить правильность значений полей

Tags: jquery

```
  <p class="err"></p>
    <input id="inp1" type="email" name="name" placeholder="почта" required><br>
    <input  type="password" name="pass" placeholder="пароль" required><br><br><br>
    <a  class="submit" href="">Вход</a><br><br>



    <script>
$(function(){
$('.submit').click(function(){
var inp1 = $('#inp1').value;
var inp2 = $('#inp2').value;
var url = "https://www.ru";
if(inp1 == 'exmp@mail.ru' && inp2 == 'exp111'){
$(location).attr('href',url);
}else{
$('err').setText('Ошибка');
}
});

});


</script>
```

При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит, страница просто обновляется, что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Много ошибок допустили: второй инпут без **`id`**, **`setText`** взяли из **`java`**, клик по тегу **`a`** вызывает "незаглушённое" действие по умолчанию, значение инпута считывается через **`val()`**.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.submit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // предотвращаем распространение события по умолчанию
    var inp1 = $('#inp1').val();
    var inp2 = $('#inp2').val();
    var url = "https://www.ru";
    if (inp1 == 'exmp@mail.ru' && inp2 == 'exp111') {
      document.location.href =  url;
    } else {
      $('.err').html('Ошибка');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="err"></p>
<input id="inp1" type="email" name="name" placeholder="почта" required><br>
<input id="inp2" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="пароль" required><br><br><br>
<a class="submit" href="">Вход</a><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Касательно переадресации:
$(location).attr('href',url); заменить на window.location.href = url;
И рекомендую сделать через стандартную form, так же надеюсь вы в курсе что javascript доступ пользователям Вашего сайта и они получат доступ к "inp2 == 'exp111'"